# How to use Localization in Shared Project? Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, localization, project, shared

I want to make a multilanguage program via using resources(.resw files).
Its really easy for PCL but I dont know how to do it in Shared Project?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Portable Class Library (PCL, or just Class Library Project) using .NET Standard, in order to localize resources in a Xamarin.Forms shared project.

Create the PCL, and then reference it from all 3 projects (Android, iOS, UWP).

Using a naming convention like AppResource.resx for the main resource, select that code generation should be Public, from inside the resource editor (in the top toolbar, there is a drop-down.)

Afterward, create a resource filed named AppResources.fr-FR.resx for French, for example. Always use the format ResourceFile.Language.resx.

Code generation will automatically be disabled for the localized resource when you name it, by the project manager.  Keep it that way.  It doesn't need code generation.

Voilà!  You can now access localized resources from a shared Xamarin.Forms app using a Portable Class Library.

Now you can follow the rest of **[This Tutorial From Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=vswin)** from within the PCL.

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem of being unable to localize a *shared* project. PCL != shared project

Comment: I know.  You have to create a PCL and add a reference to each of your build projects, Android, iOS, etc.  Shared projects cannot be localized from within the shared project, itself.  You need to build a separate PCL.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced some day ago the same problem (and with .net standard there isn't documentation about it).
I've created a library to do quickly the localization also in shared project.
Hope it helps:
https://github.com/andreabbondanza/DewXamarinLocalization